# Dynamic URL rewrite help using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can I achieve this

```
Existing URL :
newsDetails.php?cid=1&nid=$5698
```

so I want to rewrite to new URL :

```
news-1/details/1000
```

contents of .htaccess file :

```
# For security reasons, Option all cannot be overridden.
#Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^news-(\d+)/[^/]+/(\d+)/?$ newsDetails.php?cid=$1&nid=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: htaccess cannot query the database

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^news-(\d+)/[^/]+/(\d+)/?$ newsDetails.php?cid=$1&nid=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: **Not working** comment is of little use. Need answers of all of these questions. Q0. What URL are you entering in your browser? Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is full path of above .htaccess?

Comment: www.mysite.com/newsDetails.php?cid=1&nid=5698 there is no any .htaccess file in this folder (mysite.com). the code in .htaccess is in question now. the full path will be www.mysite.com/.htaccess

Comment: That's the problem. This rule is to support your pretty URL i.e.: `www.mysite.com/news-1/details/1000`.

Comment: I did not get you. I mean there is no any OTHER .htaccess file in this folder (other than only one .htaccess). Where is the problem ?

Comment: FYI. wordpress works nicely on this server (difference folder)

Comment: This rule is for supporting your pretty URL scheme. It is not for redirecting `www.mysite.com/newsDetails.php?cid=1&nid=5698 ` back to `www.mysite.com/news-1/details/5698`. Since we don't know value of `details` here.

Comment: In question I have clearly mentioned newsDetails.php?cid=1&nid=$5698 to what url

Comment: this is not for WP. so I don't feel mentioning wordpress

Comment: In the very first comment on your question I wrote **htaccess cannot query the database** If `detail` of the new url isn't in the original URL i.e. `www.mysite.com/newsDetails.php?cid=1&nid=5698` it cannot be added in the pretty URL.

Answer (score 0):

I prefere to realize it full in PHP. U need only a rewrite like

```
....
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

If u want to use your existing URLs, then make PHP redirects from the old files.